# how can i get the value of a child in firebase database realtime in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to be able to obtain the data that is inside `grupofav`, this data is equivalent to `grupoid3`, but I cannot access the reference that is equivalent to that value in firebase database real-time, the idea is to be able to pass the id of the favourite group to another reference accessing that particular group.

I tried doing this

```
var grupoFav = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref()
  .child("usuarios")
  .child("T1gMWDq6d6R6cKSyd8StjKV8drg1")
  .child("grupofav")
  .get()
  .toString();
```

but with get, onvalue and others, I couldn't get to the data

[image: image refence]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` is an asynchronous operation, so you'll need to `await` its result:

```
var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref()
  .child("usuarios")
  .child("T1gMWDq6d6R6cKSyd8StjKV8drg1")
  .child("grupofav")
var snapshot = await dbRef.get(); //  Use await here
var grupoFav = snapshot.value;    //  Use value here
```

Comment: Thanks! You have found the answer, it had not occurred to me to use await, although I had used something similar in another part of the code, but I am beginning to understand little by little, I have been very fascinated by Firebase and Flutter!

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref()
  .child("usuarios")
  .orderByChild('groupfav')
  .get();
```

Comment: hello! that doesn't work for me, because technically I don't know the id called "grupoid3", I only know "grupoid", but not its value

Comment: please check again,i have updated it

Comment: I tried it there, but it gives me the following error "get for query /users falling back to disk cache after error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "groupfav", for path "/users", to the rules"